# Can't hand an ArrayList to out of an AsyncTask into an Activity (Android)

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-asynctask, static

I try to over give an ArrayList out of an AsyncTask into an Activity. But the result is an NullPointerException.

Here ist my Code

**The Async Task**

```
ArrayList<String> listString = new ArrayList<String>();

private class gettingEvents extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String tableName = makeTableName();

        try {

            String url = "jdbc:mysql://"+server+":"+port+"/"+dbName;
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
            Statement statement = null;
            String  sqlCommand = null;

            DatabaseMetaData md = (DatabaseMetaData) connection.getMetaData();
            ResultSet rsDB = md.getTables(dbName,null,null,null);
            while (rsDB.next()){

                ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();

                String currTableName = rsDB.getString("TABLE_NAME");

                statement = connection.createStatement();
                sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM " + currTableName;
                ResultSet rsTB = statement.executeQuery(sqlCommand);
                while(rsTB.next()){
                    players.add(new Player(rsTB.getString("name"),rsTB.getInt("money"), rsTB.getInt("tip")));
                }

                listString.add(makeEventString(currTableName, players));

            }

            connection.close();

        }catch (SQLException sqle){

        }

        viewEventsActivity.setEventsToView(listString);

        return null;
    }
}
```

**The receiving class:**

```
public class ViewEventsActivity  extends AppCompatActivity {

MySQLHandler mySQLHandler = new MySQLHandler();;

static ListView lvShowEvents;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_viewevents);

    lvShowEvents = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvShowEvents);

    mySQLHandler.startGettingEvents();
}

public void setEventsToView(ArrayList<String> listStringArray){

    ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ViewEventsActivity.this, R.layout.list_items, listStringArray);

    lvShowEvents.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    lvShowEvents.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
```

}

And this is the LogCat:

```
01-05 22:14:55.875 32144-32382/de.aintlarry.patsch E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                                                                     Process: de.aintlarry.patsch, PID: 32144
                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void de.aintlarry.patsch.ViewEventsActivity.setEventsToView()' on a null object reference
                                                                         at de.aintlarry.patsch.MySQLHandler$gettingEvents.doInBackground(MySQLHandler.java:237)
                                                                         at de.aintlarry.patsch.MySQLHandler$gettingEvents.doInBackground(MySQLHandler.java:200)
                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I think it's caused by an wrong type (Static, public, etv.) of a variable or method. Is my Supposition correct?

I can't find my mistake.

Comment: viewEventsActivity is null, what activity is your async task being called in?

Comment: And after you fixed the null pointer, you will get problems since you want to update the ui from a background thread.

Comment: The AsyncTask ist called out of a void in the same Class. (no Activity) 
This void is called by the onCreate Method of the ViewEventsActivity.

Comment: I've had fixed the NullPointerException. Thanks for your help. 

But how can i fix, the Problem while Updating the UI from the BackgroundThread?

Answer (score 0):

This line from your logcat:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void de.aintlarry.patsch.ViewEventsActivity.setEventsToView()' on a null object referenc
```

indicates that viewEventsActivity is null when you execute setEventsToView on it. I dont see in your code where viewEventsActivity is declared / initialized. If your AsyncTask is nested in your activity class then you can access setEventToView with: `ViewEventsActivity.this.setEventsToView(listString);` - but whats important is that you should do it from `onPostExecute` of your AsyncTask - it is executed on UI thread and this is where you are allowd to update views.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 

My AsyncTask is in my "MySQLHandler" Class. So it isn't nested in the Activity. 

This is how i declared the ViewEventsActivity 

ViewEventsActivity viewEventsActivity;

Comment: Ok,but viewEventsActivity is null and that is why you get your error, if it is inside MySQLHandler then you need to pass ViewEventsActivity.this to it.